# I want to monitor an apache application using check_mk

Tags: check-mk

I want to monitor an apache application on check_mk. When searching for it on the official site I get to this link https://checkmk.com/integrations/apache_status . Question where is the plugin so that I can install it ?

Tried to search for the plugin, didn't find it on the official website

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file plugin file, along with all other plugin files and sometimes even configuration examples in your Checkmk site. It is located in the Setup menu under "Linux".

The same works for Windows and other operating systems.